# StaggeredGridLayoutManager not working for recyclerView

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have developed code it shows images from server in gridview,but stageredgridview is not working.
Below is my code

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, personNames, personImages);



recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);


 recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: post your code..

Comment: Please check the code.

Comment: I had same problem. I checked twice & resolved  myself. Good luck

Comment: @shwetac: check if the received images from server are of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    }


 private void setAdapter() {
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Well thisis  the standard format ... please check your adapter ....there is probably error in your adapter.

Comment: yes, Problem is resolved by removing resize property from adapter.